# Prove linear programming is a special case of quadratic programming

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, quadratic-programming

If quadratic programming (QP) encompasses linear programming (LP) for optimization problems, so that every LP is a QP, how can this fact be proven/derived mathematically (elimination or otherwise) from the following quadratic function?

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^{\text{T}}Ax + c^{\text{T}}x + d$$

And with the reformulation, can a QP solver still be applied to the LP problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $A$ as the zero matrix. Then $f(x)=c^tx+d$ is a linear objective function.

Comment: with this reformulation, can a QP solver still be applied to the LP problem?

Comment: Indeed, seems like.

Comment: how would using a QP solver on an LP problem differ from the solution obtained from an LP solver? just because a QP solver is used, it cannot be said that its solution is a global minimum as would be the case of convex optimization problems that QP is really intended for can it

Comment: the solution will be the same, although a QP solver might be less efficient because it is less specialized